# QGIS Clipping raster with vector-getting all touching pixels

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

Is there a setting I can change in order to get all the pixels of the raster layer which are touched by the vector boundary in the clipped image? Right now, only those pixels which lie completely within the boundary are included, and it's causing issues.

Answer (score 3):

I've not tried this, but there appears to be an [option in gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/structGDALWarpOptions.html) called  [CutlineAllTouched](http://www.gdal.org/structGDALWarpOptions.html#a0ed77f9917bb96c7a9aabd73d4d06e08)

> **CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED**: This defaults to FALSE, but may be set to TRUE to enable ALL_TOUCHEd mode when rasterizing cutline polygons. This is useful to ensure that that all pixels overlapping the cutline polygon will be selected, not just those whose center point falls within the polygon.

You should be able to call this using the **wo** (warp option). You should be able to edit the command line using the 'pencil' icon to add this option when using **Raster>Projections>Warp**

```
gdalwarp -wo CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE ... other settings...
```