# QGIS clipping raster with CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, gdalwarp

How should the `CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED` option in **gdalwarp** (referenced [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250893/qgis-clipping-raster-with-vector-getting-all-touching-pixels)) be used to correctly include all of the touching pixels of a vector boundary to a clipped image?

As can be seen below, the output file has nan and 0 values rather than containing a clipped raster as expected:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your cutline is valid?

Comment: @user30184 yes, it is valid

Comment: A more accurate question: Is the cutline having the same SRS than the image and is it at least partially inside the image area?

Comment: @user30184 yes, the cutline and image are both EPSG 32718 and overlap

Comment: EPSG:32718 is UTM zone 18 South, that's far away from Israel?