# Clipped raster not appearing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

Setup: I have a project (UTM 84 zone 36N) with a digital elevation map (30 meters) of Israel and a GeoJSON loaded into QGIS. Both appear fine.

Task: I want to clip the DEM, using the GeoJSON. Because the GeoJSON is narrower than 30 meters, in places, I am using the warp tool, with the "CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE" specification, in order to include all of the pixels.

Here is my code:

`gdalwarp -wo CUTLINE_ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE -overwrite 
-s_srs EPSG:32636 -t_srs EPSG:32636 -multi -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline 
C:\...\geojsonSample.txt -dstalpha -of GTiff 
C:\...\IsraelDEM.tif C:/.../clippedDEM.tif`

Problem: sometimes, the resulting clip has appropriate elevation data, but does not appear on the canvas. Sometimes it gives me all 0s or infinite values for elevations. Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: Do all affected layers have the same CRS?

Comment: Yes, they do. UTM 84 zone 36N.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251169/qgis-clipping-raster-with-cutline-all-touched?